# Starting meteor on server results in unhandled error event

Tags: node.js, meteor

Im trying to run meteor on my server but everytime I want to start my app with 'meteor' it gives me this error:

[image]

Full console log:

```
[nakroma@dubhe twitchPriority]$ /home/nakroma/bin/meteor
[[[[[ /var/www/virtual/nakroma/html ]]]]]

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

On google I only find stuff related to meteor-up but not the actual meteor.

Comment: please share your full error message.

Comment: That is the full erorr message. I edited the full console log, when I start meteor only this appears.